# Find the total number of rows and columns in the worksheet - Microsoft Graph

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

With Microsoft Graph I can access all the rows and columns from a worksheet like this.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/usedRange
```

This is giving me the entire data of the worksheet. But I want only the total rows and columns like this,

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#workbookRange",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.workbookRange",
    "@odata.id": "/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000%7D%27)/usedRange",
    "address": "Sheet1!A1:CE6",
    "addressLocal": "Sheet1!A1:CE6",
    "columnCount": 83,
    "cellCount": 498,
    "rowCount": 6,
    "rowIndex": 0
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can try adding `?select`
Like this :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/usedRange$select=address,addressLocal,cellCount,columnCount,rowCount,rowIndex
```

[Link from documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=http#select-parameter)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You can try following vba script:

```
Sub TotalRows()
     Dim TotalRow As Integer
     TotalRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    End Sub
```